# Invalid argument in getContactsByCustomField

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a google apps script to keep my contacts in sync with a spreadsheet of contacts.  We have a lot of contacts with no emails, so I needed to create a custom unique id.  As these contacts are added via a Google form (by one staff member only), it made sense (to me) to just use the timestamp as the unique id.

So in my script, I'm checking for matching contacts using this custom field, as follows:

```
//get the time stamp from the spreadsheet
var timeStamp = sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
//find contacts with that timestamp in their Time Stamp field
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField(timeStamp, 'Time Stamp');
```

The second line (20th line in my function) throws this error:

```
Invalid argument (line 20, file "Code")
```

I notice in the google API reference that the second parameter to `getContactsbyCustomField` needs to be an 'extended field', but the example provided suggests I can name this what I want.

I'm a bit lost on how to fix this. 10 years since I last did any decent coding, and that was mostly PHP/MySQL stuff, so feeling like I'm back at coding pre-school at the moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you get the Timestamp with the following line of code it is casting it to a Date object;

```
var timeStamp = sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
```

You would expect a value like `12/14/2015 9:50:03` but you are really getting a value like `Mon Dec 14 2015 09:50:03 GMT-0500 (EST)`

I'm not sure if this is working as intended or if an issue needs to be raised.

I was able to fix this by converting the date when I added it as a custom field.

```
var c = ContactsApp.createContact(e.namedValues["First Name"],e.namedValues["Last Name"] , e.namedValues["Email"]);
    c.addCustomField("Time Stamp", new Date(e.namedValues["Timestamp"]).toString());
```

You will also need to convert the read in value to a string also.

```
//get the time stamp from the spreadsheet
var timeStamp = sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
//find contacts with that timestamp in their Time Stamp field
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField(timeStamp.toString(), 'Time Stamp');
```

Comment: Thanks for that help Spencer. Problem solved.  Also appreciate you anticipating what would surely have been my next question - how do I add that value to the contact.  Ta.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and accept the answer so others can find this solution.